# bxslider load more slide, detect when reaches the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bxslider

I have a horizontal carousel slider with bxslider. I have turned off the infiniteLoop to not allow slider to circle.
I want to load more slides with AJAX request and append to slider once the slider is reaches to the end.
So first i am loading 10 slides, then want to load more 10 when slider reaches to the end. Here how i am loading slider.

```
$('.bxslider_read').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 3,
        maxSlides: 6,
        slideWidth: 110,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager:false,
        infiniteLoop:false,
        mode: 'horizontal'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a callback function onSlideNext:function(){ /*check for next slide if last load data from ajax and append to slider and move to loaded side*/ }

Then you complete code looks like:-

```
var sliderSelector = '.bxslider_read';
sliderInstance = $(sliderSelector).bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 6,
  slideWidth: 110,
  slideMargin: 10,
  pager:false,
  infiniteLoop:false,
  mode: 'horizontal',
  onSlideNext: function(slideEl, oldSlide, newSlide){
    /* we are loading next slides as we reaches last slide */
    if(sliderInstance.getSlideCount() == (newSlide + 1)){
      $.ajax({
        url:"url to load next slides",
        success:function(data){
          /* response from server must be slide elements */
          $(sliderSelector).append(data);
          /* we need to restart slider */
          sliderInstance.reloadSlider();
          sliderInstance.goToSlide(sliderInstance.getCurrentSlide());
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: When i am reloading the slider and call to goToSlide function, slider is stops working, but when i am removing that function,  slider always stays at the first position. And the very first time it is loading more items ,it seams like slider is not reloading, http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ed4l0lj0d

Answer (score 0):

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                pager: false,
                controls: false,
                infiniteLoop: false,
            });

            $('#pronext').click(function () {
                //return false;
                var current = slider.getCurrentSlide() + 1;
                var total = slider.getSlideCount();
                if (current == total) {
                    alert('Finished');
                }
                slider.goToNextSlide();
            });
          });
```